# A problem on simplification $\operatorname{Li_3}\frac{1}{3}$

Tags: calculus, riemann-zeta, polylogarithm

Can you simplify $$\large\operatorname{Li_3} \frac{1}{3} $$

It might be impotant to note that $$\operatorname{Li_3}\frac{1}{2}=\frac{7\zeta(3)}{8}+\frac{\log^3 2}{6}-\frac{\pi^2\log 2}{12}$$

But I do not know enough properties of Polylogarithms to solve it.

Comment: As far as polylogarithms are concerned, the arguments $\pm1$ and $\dfrac12$ are special. Others, not so much.

Comment: @Lucian I thought that there might be. So there absolutely is none?